# PHP - Inspecting session max lifetime within the code

Tags: php, session

How do you inspect the value assigned to `session.gc_maxlifetime`?
Obviousely this does not work:

```
echo session.gc_maxlifetime;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`ini_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php)...

```
echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```